# Can we apply for Individual Tax Payer Identification(ITIN) for the first time in the out of tax season?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, itin

I am new to the US and just arrived here on May 31, but what I need is having ITIN to get credit card, etc. But someone told me you must at least wait until the next year's tax season that will start from Jan 2022, because you must file a tax return and attach it to the W7 form. Is that right? There is no way to get it in the out of tax season?

Comment: For a lot of us (like people who make estimated tax payments), tax season is all year.  Indeed, that should also be the case if you're regularly employed, since your employer will need to withhold tax.  See the IRS information: https://www.irs.gov/individuals/individual-taxpayer-identification-number

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Friend's comment was utterly nonsensical.  You can get one anytime - just phone them.  (Over in the US, the IRS is actually *incredibly* helpful on the phone and also by mail etc. Go for it.)

Comment: @Fattie: Thank you so much. I must go to the IRS Sacramento branch and I could find their phone number(916-974-5225) but I couldn't find their email address. May you please help me to find their email address?

Comment: they don't use email.  just telephone

Comment: @Fattie: Incredibly annoying.  So 20th century, you know.

Comment: @jamesqf - you're so right!

Comment: @jamesqf: most foreigners are not allowed to be employed in US (including F-2, which OP identifies in their other Q); those who are authorized to be employed are permitted to get SSN and required to use it, and (as your link says) you cannot get ITIN if you are eligible for SSN. And incidentally nonresident aliens in US employed _by a foreign government or international organization_ are usually not subject to US tax _or_ withholding.

Answer (score 1):

What you were told is true in general. Most ITIN applications (W-7) can only be filed with a tax return. There are five exceptions that allow you to apply at any time (without a tax return), per the [W-7 instructions](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/iw7.pdf):

- > **Exception 1**. Passive income—third-party withholding or tax treaty
  > benefits. This exception may apply if you’re the recipient of
  > partnership income, interest income, annuity income, rental income, or
  > other passive income that’s subject to third-party withholding or
  > covered by tax treaty benefits.
- > **Exception 2**. Other income. This exception may apply if:
  >
  > - 1. You’re claiming the benefits of a U.S. income tax treaty with a foreign country and you receive any of the following.
  >
  >   - a. Wages,
  >     salary, compensation, and honoraria payments;
  >   - b. Scholarships,
  >     fellowships, and grants; and/or
  >   - c. Gambling income; or
  > - 2. You’re receiving taxable scholarship, fellowship, or grant income, but not claiming the benefits of an income tax treaty.
- > **Exception 3**. Mortgage interest—third-party reporting. This exception
  > may apply if you have a home mortgage loan on real property you own in
  > the United States that’s subject to third-party reporting of mortgage
  > interest. S
- > **Exception 4**. Dispositions by a foreign person of U.S. real property
  > interest—third-party withholding. This exception may apply if you’re a
  > party to a disposition of a U.S. real property interest by a foreign
  > person, which is generally subject to withholding by the transferee or
  > buyer (withholding agent). This exception may also apply if you have a
  > notice of non-recognition under Regulations section 1.1445-2(d)
- > **Exception 5**. Treasury Decision (TD) 9363. This exception may apply if
  > you have an IRS reporting requirement as a non-U.S. representative of
  > a foreign corporation who needs to obtain an ITIN for the purpose of
  > meeting their e-filing requirement under TD 9363 and are submitting
  > Form W-7 with Form 13350, Registration for e-services.

Refer to the [W-7 instructions](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/iw7.pdf) for more complete information on the exceptions and information about which documents must be provided for each one. I'd probably consult an expert in your region if you think you meet the requirements for one of the exceptions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. May you see my other question here: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/66773/i-just-arrived-to-the-us-with-the-f-2-students-dependent-visa-can-i-get-an-i

Comment: But how can you file a tax return if you don't already have an ITIN?

Comment: @jamesqf Per the Form W-7 instructions: "Enter “ITIN TO BE REQUESTED” wherever your SSN or
ITIN is requested. An ITIN will be issued only after you file a tax
return and meet all other requirements." (that's in the context of not qualifying for an exception and having a filing requirement that isn't satisfied by a 1040-ES which doesn't require an SSN/ITIN.

Comment: @HartCO: What if I open an account in a brokerage then buy and sell few stocks? Can I immediately apply for ITIN after one buy and sell or I also must to wait upto the next year for filing a tax return and getting an ITIN?